# PHP convert non standard marks and special characters to normal

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, unicode-normalization

Is there a way to convert characters like:

```
É É é à Ç etc
```

and also this type of exclamation mark with a space after it built in:

```
！
```

To their normal versions. At the moment I have code like this:

```
$linesvalue = str_replace(["Ç","ç"],"ç",$linesvalue);
$linesvalue = str_replace(["É","É","é"],"é",$linesvalue);
$linesvalue = str_replace("è","è",$linesvalue);
$linesvalue = str_replace("à","à",$linesvalue);
$linesvalue = str_replace("â","â",$linesvalue);
$linesvalue = str_replace("ê","ê",$linesvalue);
```

They look like they're replacing with the same thing, but they're certainly not. Anyway, this is not too bad but I find when I try to replace the exclamation mark (！) in particular it seems to also replace some accented characters like ü and such.

Is there a way to convert the whole text in advance so its just all standard characters?

Comment: Are you doing this because they appear broken in some way if you don't?

Comment: Use [normalization form](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) C to normalize combining marks like accents. Form KC should additionally convert full-width characters like U+FF01 to standard versions.

Comment: That sounds interesting - do you want to post this as an answer? Not quite sure exactly how its implemented from the link you gave anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [normalization form](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) C to normalize combining marks like accents. Form KC additionally converts full-width characters like U+FF01 to standard versions.

Example:

```
<?php
$string = "É É é à Ç ！";
print "before: $string\n";
print "hex: " . unpack("H*", $string)[1] . "\n";
$string = Normalizer::normalize($string, Normalizer::FORM_KC);
print "after: $string\n";
print "hex: " . unpack("H*", $string)[1] . "\n";
```

Output:

```
before: É É é à Ç ！
hex: c3892045cc812065cc812061cc802043cca720efbc81
after: É É é à Ç !
hex: c38920c38920c3a920c3a020c3872021
```